# Robot in a grid

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

This was recently asked to someone I know.

> A robot has to move in a grid which is in the form of a matrix. It can go to
>
> 1. A(i,j)--> A(i+j,j) (Down)
> 2. A(i,j)--> A(i,i+j) (Right)
>
> Given it starts at (1,1) and it has to go to A(m,n), find the minimum number of STEPS it has to take to get to (m,n) and write

```
    public static int minSteps(int m,int n)
```

> For instance to go from (1,1) to m=3 and n=2 it has to take (1, 1) ->
>   (1, 2) -> (3, 2) i.e. 2 steps

Unfortunately for my friend answered it as though it was the [other](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=4539687) well known question of finding number of unique paths.

How to solve to find min number of steps taken to reach m,n?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my algo is wrong, and I've misunderstood the question,  I've edited my question after understanding it correctly.

Comment: The example of (1,1) to (3,2) in two steps seems to imply that the definition of a step is a single movement of any length parallel to either axis.  Is that correct?

Comment: A single step is (i+j) along either axis.

Comment: It would be clearer to say that the length of a step along one axis is the value of the position on the opposite axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something interesting happens when we ask, "What happens if we go backwards?".

So we want to go from A(i+j, j) -> A(i, j) to go left, and A(i, i+j) -> A(i, j) to go up.  Since things could get confusing if I kept using i and j, I'm going to use x and y, and say that we're going backward from A(x, y) whether we're going left or up.

We get these formulas:

> Left: A(x, y) -> A(x-y, y)
>
> Up: A(x, y) -> A(x, y-x)

First thing to notice: if x=y, then we get a 0 coordinate in both formulas, so we know that anything on the diagonal that isn't our starting point is unreachable.

Second thing to notice: we have x-y in one formula and y-x in the other.  Since x and y are always positive, *at least one of the two possible locations we could have come from is impossible*.

That means we can figure out exactly which square we came from, unless the square is unreachable, in which case it either is a diagonal square, or it came from a diagonal square.  By backtracking all the way from a reachable square, we get the *only* path, which must be the path with the smallest length.

---

The following is my solution to the problem that was originally presented:

There is only one way for j to change, and when it does, it increases by 1 because the robot stepped to the right.  We know j started at 1 and ended at n, so we know how many steps to the right it took.

Same thing with i and steps down.

Which path it took is irrelevant.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the problem as posted, but it seems so trivial that I suspect the OP has misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I did misunderstand the question, now corrected

Comment: Am I reading it wrongly? When you change j (move down) you do it by **i** not by 1. Therefore the number of down steps you need depends on how many rightward (increasing i) steps you have taken and where in the sequence they happened.

Comment: @JuliaHayward This answer was correct for the [original version of the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/275676/revisions).

Comment: Aha, thanks! (Though I have seen too many interview candidates fail questions that trivial...)

Answer (score 3):

This is a dynamic programming problem. The idea is to try all paths and return the minimum number of steps taken each time.

```
int MinSteps( int posX, int posY, int destX, int destY)
{
    // if we reached the destination
    if (posX == destX && posY == destY)
      return 0;

     // if we didn't reach the dest we need to penalize this path so we return INT_MAX
    if (posX >= arraySizeX || posY >= arraySizeY )
     return INT_MAX;

  return min( MinSteps(posX+posY, posY), MinSteps(posX, posY+posX) ) + 1;
}
```

Since we are recalculating the same path several times, An *obvious* optimization is to use memoization to store the min steps take so far.

```
// Table should be init with INT_MAX except the first column with 0.
int MinSteps( int posX, int posY, int destX, int destY, int** table)
{
    // if we reached the destination
    if (posX == destX && posY == destY)
      return 0;

     // if we didn't reach the dest, we need to penalize this path so we return INT_MAX
    if (posX >= arraySizeX || posY >= arraySizeY )
     return INT_MAX;

   // If we already calculate this paths min steps we only look it up
   if (table[posX][posY] != INT_MAX)
    return table[posX][posY];

  table[posX][posY]= min( MinSteps(posX+posY, posY), MinSteps(posX, posY+posX) ) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is tricky. The min number of steps is m + n - 2. The question is really about is there a path with the given restriction.

Comment: @InstructedA My solution will return INT_MAX if there isn't any path, otherwise we can modify the function to return bool and the min steps. The question isn't that tricky.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be brute-forced using breadth-first search.

Simplest algorithm using queue. The performance could be improved by remembering points that were already visited. And because you are using breath-first, you are sure the previously visited locations were closer. (sorry for C# code).

```
    private struct Location
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Distance { get; set; }
    }

    public static int minSteps(int m, int n)
    {
        Queue<Location> locations = new Queue<Location>();
        locations.Enqueue(new Location(){X = 1, Y = 1, Distance = 0});

        while(locations.Count > 0)
        {
            var loc = locations.Dequeue();

            // if it reached the target location
            if(loc.X == m && loc.Y == n)
            {
                return loc.Distance;
            }

            // if we went past the location then this path is invalid
            if(loc.X > m || loc.Y > n)
                continue;

            locations.Enqueue(new Location{ X = loc.X + loc.Y, Y = loc.Y, Distance = loc.Distance+1});
            locations.Enqueue(new Location{ X = loc.X, Y = loc.X + loc.Y, Distance = loc.Distance + 1 });
        }

        throw new Exception("No path found!");
    }
```

Comment: You probably mean "breadth-first search".

Answer (score 0):

Here's one - and I was told this is on the lines of what the interviewer was looking for

> 1.) If m > n, then m-=n i.e. he could only have come from (m-n,n)
>
> 2.) Else if m < n, then n-=m i.e. he could only have come from (m,n-m)
>
> and this is followed by the edge cases and housekeeping

```
 int minSteps(int m, int n)
        {
            if(m<=1 || n <=1) return -1;
            int count = 0;
            while(abs(m-n) && m>=1 && n>=1)
            {
                if(m>n)
                    m=m-n;
                else n = n-m;
                count++;
            }
            if(m==1 && n==1)
                return count;
            else return -1;
        }
```

This is taken from [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5697293959299072)

Answer (score -3):

Here is the best solution with minimum time complexity of O(mn).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Robot4x4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a[][]=new int [4][4];
        int p=count(a,4,4);
        System.out.println("Total Path are:"+p);
    }

    public static int count(int a[][],int m,int n)
    {
        int p[][]=new int [m][n];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            p[i][0]=1;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            p[0][j]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<m;i++)
            for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
                p[i][j]=p[i-1][j]+p[i][j-1];
        return p[m-1][n-1];
    }
}
```

If you have any doubt with the logic then watch this video which will help you to understand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHu2LWzAwps

Comment: First of all, proof by youtube video isn't exactly a good idea. Secondly - you've solved the *other* problem, not the one OP asked about. OP wanted the min number of steps in a path to the objective, not the number of paths. You have also completely disregarded the actual text of the task and assumed the robot can go down or right by 1 each time, which is not the case.